# The transition/difference between Citadel and Fortess

Tags: gazebo-citadel, ignition-fortress, ignition-citadel

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there!

I wanted to test my current file on Fortress but it seems that there's few ign syntax are not supported on Fortress from Citadel.

[image: image description]

Is there any doc about this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27463/the-transition/difference-between-citadel-and-fortess/) by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 87 on 2021-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2021-10-14**:
could you please include the whole SDF file? thanks!

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2021-10-14**:
Absolutely!!! [Here](https://github.com/feagi/feagi-core/blob/feature-feature-doc-ign-foxy-draft-part3/third_party/gazebo/smart_car/freenove_4wd_car_description/models/sdf/freenove_smart_car.sdf)

THank you so much!

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2021-10-14**:
Perfect. I added some instructions to my answer to check SDFormat spec. Not difficult to solve your problem I think.

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2021-10-14**:
Nice! Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Main change probably affecting you is the update from sdformat9 to sdformat12 which, indeed, has some improvements that generates some incompatibilities. [SDFormat has its own migration guide](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/sdformat/blob/sdf12/Migration.md). I sometimes found useful to run `ign sdf --check` (ignition-tools package) to get some hints about what's going on.

Another useful resource is the SDFormat spec. In your case http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.8&elem=material says that ambient should in range 0,1 and you are using 2.0 in your file. This is not the only problem but the rest can be fixed using error output and spec.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2021-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kakcalu13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51973/kakcalu13/) on 2021-10-14**:
Ah, gotcha! I'm going to try that one out!

Does it need for me to have both versions?

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2021-10-14**:
There is a nice option in "ign sdf check --versions" that should tell you which versions are found in the system and "ign sdf --force-version " to make the tool to use different versions and compare results. In your case I would run against both, 9.x and 12.x, but look for the output in 12.x to see if it helps. Good luck.